# How to get Amazon s3 Encrypted object with signed URL?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I have created a signed URL for my s3 object.

The object is stored using 'Server-Side Encryption with Customer-Provided Encryption Keys'.

Now, When my client browses to the signed URL he gets :

> The object was stored using a form of Server Side Encryption. The correct parameters must be provided to retrieve the object

I need somehow make my client send the "x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm" and "x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key" headers before reaching the URL.

Any idea how can I achieve that ?

Comment: That method looks like it requires your key to be provided as part of the URL. Do you really want this to be the access method? If you used Server Side Encryption (the version without customer-provided keys), Amazon S3 would automatically decrypt the file without having to provide keys. That's a lot easier!

Comment: Thanks John, I need to keys to be generated in the client side (For security reasons). And, I solved my problem by configuring my s3 Cors and the CloudFront allowed methods.

Comment: Please refer to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43752154/2609095

Answer (score 3):

"x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm" and "x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key" should be used at server side when signing the URL and the client don't need to add any header to the requests.

I don't know the PHP syntax but in Java SDK it works like this:

```
 generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(BUCKET_NAME, TOKEN)
 .withSSEAlgorithm(SSEAlgorithm.KMS.getAlgorithm())
 .withKmsCmkId("YOUR_KMS_KEY_ID");
```

OR

```
 generatePresignedUrlRequest.addRequestParameter("x-amz-server-side-encryption", "aws:kms");
 generatePresignedUrlRequest.addRequestParameter("x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id", "YOUR_KMS_KEY_ID");
```

When signing for GET method you shouldn't do anything spacial.

For more info you can look at this guide: [Generating Amazon S3 Pre-signed URLs with SSE](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generating-amazon-s3-pre-signed-urls-with-sse-part-1/)

Raz

Comment: very useful answer, but it gives me https://{bucketname}.s3.amazonaws.com URL which gives me a privacy error in the browser is there a way to generate https://s3.amazonaws.com URL